# How to create a slider / carousel

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, slider

I was searching for a way to create a sliding window/panel like the one below on jQuery mobile but I could not find any examples.

[reference link](https://embed-dot-more-than-a-map.appspot.com/demos/places)

Appreciate if anyone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: it's called "carousel".

Answer (score 1):

The following code is what you are looking for:

http://codepen.io/redfrost/full/dbrgk

I think it is a good starting point.

I also invite you to see the following address ( 20 Free Responsive Jquery Carousel Slider Plugins ) :

http://designscrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/

Carousel sliders is now a must have feature in all business, portfolio or any website template. Along with fullscreen image sliders we can see that horizontal carousel image sliders works well with any website design and are implemented alongside. Sometimes slider needs to be one by third of a website page and that is where tiny carousel sliders come in with loads of transitions effects and even with responsive layout. eCommerce websites may be the best benefited from these sliders as they need to showcase many pics in an individual post or page. All code here is free to use and you may alter it according to your needs if you are already a developer.